# How to start programming?

Tags: c, linux

I read a lot of books about C/C++ in Linux and write simple programs. Now I want to try myself with some project. What you can recommend to? (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Does your project involve some graphical user interface? What do you want to code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208807/how-can-a-beginner-escape-tutorial-land-and-actually-get-programming

Comment: I recommend that you do something that interests you. No one can tell you what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know what to do and just want to get a little experience, try implementing [the towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), it's a classical programming exercise (the Wikipedia article might seem frightening at first sight, but the actual algorithm is dead-simple and you'll find lots of material about it online, even a lot of sample implementations). First, start with a text-only solution that just prints numbers. Then, try to "draw" the towers using ASCII art. You can also do this with a GUI, but as a novice it's easiest to start with text-based version.

Comment: I don't think implementing some algorithms is a good way to start if you want to have fun while programming.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Well, it does something and you can easily expand it once the core is done. And doing Tetris is probably too much for a first project, that can follow later on ;-)